# Migrate trained Spacy 2 pipelines to Spacy 3

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I've been using spacy 2.3.1 until now and have trained and saved a couple of pipelines for my custom Language class. But now using spacy 3.0 and `spacy.load('model-path')` I'm facing problems such as `config.cfg file not found` and other kinds of errors.

Do I have to train the models from scratch after upgrading the spacy? Is there any step-by-step guide for migrating trained models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to just migrate the trained pipelines. The pipelines trained with v2 are not compatible with v3, so you won't be able to just use `spacy.load` on them.

You'll have to migrate your codebase to v3, and retrain your models. You have two options:

- Update your training loop to change the API calls from v2 to v3, cf for more details here: https://spacy.io/usage/v3#migrating
- (recommended approach): transform your training code entirely to the new [config system](https://spacy.io/usage/training#config) in v3. While this may seem like a big difference, you'll get the hang of the config system quite quickly, and you'll notice how much more powerful & convenient it is, as compared to writing everything yourself from scratch. To get started with the config system, have a look at the [`init config`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-config) command, e.g.:

```
python -m spacy init config config.cfg --lang en --pipeline ner,textcat --optimize accuracy
```

This will provide you some sensible defaults to start from, and a config file that you can customize further according to your requirements.